# What is the meaning of " which must have followed shortly afterwards" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Of Sapor III., his brother and successor, two facts only are recorded - his conclusion of the treaty with the Romans in A.D. 384, and his war with the Arabs of the tribe of Yad, which must have followed shortly afterwards.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, historians do not know the exact date of the war between Sapor and the Arabs, but they are sure that it must have happened (very probably happened) soon after the treaty of 384.